# Creating a new object from Android update() loop

Tags: android, loops

I am trying to create an Android game, but am running into trouble with one part.  I started with the Android LunarLander example project, so instead of pasting my confusing code, I will just identify the relevant section in the [sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.html).  In the updatePhysics method, I try to create a new FlyingObject (a class I created).  I receive this error for the line where I try to create the FlyingObject:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(201): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I have Googled around, and cannot figure out how I can dynamically create objects in my game.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does your FlyingObject in fact create a Handler? Have you tried calling Looper.prepare?

Comment: This got me on the right track!  I realized the FlyingObject class extends Activity.  I removed "extends Activity" and everything worked.  All those hours wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Well this error mostly comes when you are trying to Update the UI from a Non-UI thread. So, probably use `Handler` or `runOnUiThread()` to update your UI thread from a Non-UI thread.